# Algebraic connectivity of Digraphs

Tags: linear-algebra

I am wondering if some one could help me understand this notation and what is exactly being stated on line i.

Particularly, I am having a hard time understanding what the subscript of min function is representing and what lambda_2 = lambda_2(L_s) means? Does this mean 1 = Ls?

Please note that lambda_i represents the ith eigenvalue of L and delta is the disagreement vector.

Thank you in advance!

[image]